# External Hard Drive loses connection during read/write

Tags: raspbian

for a while now I have been following [HowToGeek's Guide](http://www.howtogeek.com/142044/how-to-turn-a-raspberry-pi-into-an-always-on-bittorrent-box/) to setup a Always-On BitTorrent Box.

However, I have encountered a major problem which I am unable to solve. As I am torrenting and writing to the hard drive, the hard drive will lose connection after some time.

Upon checking dmesg, this is what is shown,

> Mar 30 17:04:31 raspberrypi kernel: [ 3849.108613] net_ratelimit: 9 callbacks suppressed
>   Mar 30 17:31:55 raspberrypi kernel: [ 5492.920408] net_ratelimit: 1941 callbacks suppressed
>   Mar 30 17:38:48 raspberrypi kernel: [ 5906.787505] net_ratelimit: 12824 callbacks suppressed
>   Mar 30 17:40:41 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6018.993823] usb 1-1.2.4: USB disconnect, device number 5
>   Mar 30 17:40:47 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6025.375844] usb 1-1.2.4: new high-speed USB device number 6 using dwc_otg
>   Mar 30 17:40:47 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6025.480959] usb 1-1.2.4: New USB device found, idVendor=054c, idProduct=05bf
>   Mar 30 17:40:47 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6025.480999] usb 1-1.2.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
>   Mar 30 17:40:47 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6025.481019] usb 1-1.2.4: Product: Hard Drive
>   Mar 30 17:40:47 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6025.481036] usb 1-1.2.4: Manufacturer: Sony
>   Mar 30 17:40:47 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6025.481053] usb 1-1.2.4: SerialNumber: 22253528272D
>   Mar 30 17:40:47 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6025.487615] usb-storage 1-1.2.4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
>   Mar 30 17:40:47 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6025.492100] scsi host1: usb-storage 1-1.2.4:1.0
>   Mar 30 17:40:47 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6025.567562] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
>   Mar 30 17:40:48 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6026.492520] scsi 1:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Sony     Hard Drive       0201 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
>   Mar 30 17:40:48 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6026.497620] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] 1953525165 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/931 GiB)
>   Mar 30 17:40:48 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6026.498815] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
>   Mar 30 17:40:48 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6026.531995]  sdb: sdb1
>   Mar 30 17:40:48 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6026.537531] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
>   Mar 30 17:40:48 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6026.580959] sd 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0

My current setup consists of,
Raspberry Pi B+ Model running on Raspbian OS
Belkin Powered USB Hub F4U020
Sony 1TB Hard Drive

The Pi is being powered by the hub as well.

Thanks for any help!

31 March, 7.57pm - An update on the situation, I switched to a dedicated power supply for the Pi in question, a different one from the one I used before. Torrenting has been going fine for the past 5-6 hours.

Comment: This could be a power problem with either the drive or the Pi. My suggestion would be to disconnect the drive and measure the voltage (details here http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Troubleshooting_power_problems) if it meets the requirements. then connect the drive and repeat. I would also suggest getting a dedicated power supply for the Pi itself instead of powering it from a hub - especially one shared with an ext. drive.

Comment: I have ever used a dedicated power supply for the pi but the same issue persists. Could it be the USB hub causing problems?

Comment: This definitely sounds like power issues. Has the HD been tested at another system (e.g. Laptop or PC) and is it working fine there?

Comment: Yes. The hard disk has worked fine on other systems

Comment: `net_ratelimit: 12824 callbacks suppressed` I believe this indicates something zany is going on, because it means something *network related* is bombing syslog with so many errors they are being suppressed.  I have logs on my desktop here going back more than a year and `net_ratelimit` does not appear once.  Is there nothing before that?

Comment: @goldilocks there are log entries before that  
It is most if not all just `smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: kevent 2 may have been dropped `

Comment: The drive and the ethernet are on the same bus.  What kind of transfer speed are you getting?

Comment: @goldilocks if you're talking about ethernet speeds, my torrent is currently downloading @ 700-1100 KiB/s and uploading @ 800-1000 KiB/s

Comment: Is the filesystem on the drive NTFS, or something else?

Comment: @goldilocks. The hard drive is using exFAT

Comment: That's kind of obscure, linux wise, but I don't think a filesystem driver bug would cause the device to disconnect, which it obviously does.  My best guess is that it is some complication on the USB bus caused by whatever that ethernet problem is (the ethernet jack on the pi is connected through the USB bus).    I've done prolonged 3-4 MB/s transfers via ethernet to a USB drive with a pi enough to say it isn't a universal problem, though.   If that is the case for you, you're unlikely to find a solution; I'd try whatever you can with power just to make sure that really isn't the issue.

Comment: I was just looking through some pi logs and I did find one that does have a `net_ratelimit` incident in it but not as seriously looking as yours.  Have you checked the CPU usage when the torrent is in progress?  I know the NTFS driver can be a pig, I'm wondering if there's just too much going on.

Comment: @goldilocks I haven't really looked at CPU usage yet. Good news is, after changing the PSU for the pi, it has managed to completely dl a 36GB torrent. Bad news, the Hard Drive has disconnected again after approx. 1 full day of use, the longest it has lasted so far.

Comment: @goldilocks Upon checking dmesg, `[56625.714702] Peer 144.131.213.151:64117/51642 unexpectedly shrunk window 1378238586:1378241004 (repaired)
[56626.694655] Peer 144.131.213.151:64117/51642 unexpectedly shrunk window 1378238586:1378241004 (repaired)
[56628.654712] Peer 144.131.213.151:64117/51642 unexpectedly shrunk window 1378238586:1378241004 (repaired)
[56632.584683] Peer 144.131.213.151:64117/51642 unexpectedly shrunk window 1378238586:1378241004 (repaired) `

Comment: and `[107441.414937] usb 1-1.2.4: USB disconnect, device number 5
[107441.431917] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
[107441.431957] Result: hostbyte=0x01 driverbyte=0x00
[107441.431977] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: 
[107441.431989] cdb[0]=0x28: 28 00 22 d7 5e 70 00 00 f0 00
[107441.432051] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 584539760
[107441.432170] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
[107441.432190] Result: hostbyte=0x01 driverbyte=0x00
[107441.432206] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: 
[107441.432217] cdb[0]=0x28: 28 00 22 d7 5f 60 00 00 10 00
[107441.432270] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 584540000`

Comment: I admit my having done "prolonged 3-4 MB/s" transfers did not include any thing beyond a few hours on occasion.  So maybe you are pushing an envelope, lol.  I don't torrent but I presume it can be arbitrarily stopped and started, so maybe your best bet is to just come up with something that will check something pertinent intermittently and restart whatever if appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a powered USB hub. This is clearly a power problem with the Pi not being able to supply enough power to the drive when it mostly needs it. Check this link out: [Powered USB Hub](http://elinux.org/RPi_Powered_USB_Hubs)

Comment: I am indeed already using a powered USB hub which powers both the Pi itself and the Hard Drive. Should I explore using a different USB hub?

Comment: I think you should use a normal power unit for the pi then the hub for the external.

Comment: I've tried that before in a previous setup but the same error occurs

Comment: That's at least a 2 amp hub and Belkin doesn't regulate them (at least, the Belkin hub I have is unregulated) so power is probably not the issue.